# Getting a specific timezone in rails sql statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application I am executing the following query.

```
sql = "select A.bus_id as busid, A.stop_id as source, A.arrival as atime, B.arrival as dtime from
(SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{startStopId}) A
inner join
(SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{endStopId}) B
on A.bustag = B.bustag
where A.arrival < B.arrival
and A.arrival > #{Time.now} "
```

I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in WelcomeController#create
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '15:21:07 +0000' at line 7: select A.bus_id as busid, A.stop_id as source, A.arrival as atime, B.arrival as dtime from (SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = 25) A inner join (SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = 1) B on A.bustag = B.bustag where A.arrival < B.arrival and A.arrival > 2015-05-03 15:21:07 +0000
```

I basically want to do the following

A.arrival > EASTERN STANDARD TIME.

One thing i noticed is that Time.now seems to be giving me UTC time.

So i thought of this solution

```
#subtract 4 hours to get eastern standard time from UTC.
@time_ = Time.now -0400

 sql = "select A.bus_id as busid, A.stop_id as source, A.arrival as atime, B.arrival as dtime from
    (SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{startStopId}) A
    inner join
    (SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{endStopId}) B
    on A.bustag = B.bustag
    where A.arrival < B.arrival
    and A.arrival > #{@time_} "
```

I am still getting an error. I am not sure what to do anymore. Appreciate all help.

Comment: don't use `#{}` interpolation inside SQL strings - it leaves you vulnereable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: oh i did not notice that thanks for heads up. also can you suggest me a solution to m problem ?

Comment: I think it should be  `A.arrival > '#{Time.now}'  " `

Comment: @liuzxc thats what i originally did but for some reason it is printing the date also and therefore giving me invalid syntax error

Comment: If you want change UTC time to EST, you can have a try:  `A.arrival > '#{Time.now.in_time_zone("EST").to_s}'"`

Comment: @liuzxc I think your answer is very close still got an error but this is what i did    A.arrival > #{Time.now.in_time_zone("EST").to_s}" and this is the error it produced. http://postimg.org/image/pza6ftwx1/
One problem is that the time is 1 hour behind actual time and another is that it seems to be putting the date in there which is giving syntax error i think if we get rid of it somehow and just have time like this '9:00:00' it works fine

Comment: You have to use quotes around #{Time.now}, it works on my machine.

Comment: is `A.arrival > '#{Time.now}' "` , not `A.arrival > #{Time.now} " `, you should add single quotes, i didn't see the single quotes from image.

Comment: @liuzxc you are right but now for some reason it works however it is getting UTC time. even though we have specified EST.

Comment: also please post it as an answer so i can upvote you and accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use quotes around #{Time.now}.

For example: `"...A.arrival > '#{Time.now}' "`

If you want change UTC to EST, you can do like this:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("EST").to_s
```

Comment: sql = "select A.bus_id as busid, A.stop_id as source, A.arrival as atime, B.arrival as dtime from
(SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{startStopId}) A
inner join
(SELECT * from schedules as S where S.stop_id = #{endStopId}) B
on A.bustag = B.bustag
where A.arrival < B.arrival
and A.arrival > '#{Time.now.in_time_zone("EST").to_s}'"

It is picking up UTC time still, not picking up EST i am not sure why ugh. is there some way where we can just store utc time in a variable then subtract it by 4 hours and then pass that time?

Comment: You can test in rails console, irb(main):007:0> Time.now.zone
=> "UTC"
irb(main):008:0> Time.now.in_time_zone("EST").zone
=> "EST"

Comment: I found time zone has changed from error image, it shows `2015-05-03 11:14:28 -0500`

Comment: Yes i added quotes and error fixed but it is picking up the time as utc now i am really frustrated. is there just a way where we get time in a varaible and just add the appropriate hours on it or subtract to get est mannually and pass that time?

Comment: If you want subtract 4 hours, you can do like this #{Time.now - 4.hours}

Comment: Can you confirm your mysql use EST time zone?

Comment: i found out the issue, i am posting it as a new question maybe you can help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016883/getting-timing-of-different-format-as-one

Answer (score 0):

You can tell rails to use a specific time zone for a specific block, for example

```
Time.use_zone('UTC') do
  # your query
end
```

The code inside that block with use that time zone in it's calculations, also instead of `Time.now` use `Time.zone.now`

if you want to change your time zone application wide then do that in your `application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

Dont forget to restart the server and/or console if you changed the `application.rb`

Comment: but will that solve my error because i think Time.now by default uses UTC, so why that error? and can you also use EST instead of UTC? i want eastern standard time

Comment: I just used `UTC` as a place holder I used, you can use any time zone you want, so yea replace `UTC` with `EST`

Comment: Its not working because for some reason I still get the same syntax error
A.arrival > 2015-05-03 15:21:07 +0000
This is the format it ends up and it is not being correctly recognized

Comment: did you replace `Time.now` with `Time.zone.now` ?

Comment: you need to do the replace only if you used the `use_zone`, if you used the `application.rb` then you need to restart your server / console